# Calcul Time on django

Tags: django, time, aggregate

I have the following code:

```
def index(request):
events_list = Timesheet.objects.filter(owner = request.user.pk, week = datetime.datetime.now().isocalendar()[1]).order_by('-working_hour')
total_hours_week = Timesheet.objects.annotate(total_hours_per_week=Sum('working_hour')).filter(owner = request.user.pk,  week = datetime.datetime.now().isocalendar()[1])

return render(request, "timesheet/index.html", {'events_list': events_list, 'total_hours_week': total_hours_week})
```

the total_hours_week retun the current error:

You cannot use Sum, Avg, StdDev, and Variance aggregations on date/time fields in sqlite3 since date/time is saved as text.

Do you know how to fix ?

thanks per advance

Comment: As the error states, sqlite3 doesnt support the operation, you will have to do this programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the current DB engine is sqlite3 or not, and calculate annotations programmatically in case that is needed:

```
from django.conf import settings


def index(request):
    db_engine = settings.DATABASES['default']['ENGINE']

    if db_engine = 'django.db.backends.sqlite3':
        total_hours_week = [] # Calculate annotation programmatically
    else:
        total_hours_week = Timesheet.objects.annotate(total_hours_per_week=Sum('working_hour')).filter(owner = request.user.pk,  week = datetime.datetime.now().isocalendar()[1])
    events_list = Timesheet.objects.filter(owner = request.user.pk, week = datetime.datetime.now().isocalendar()[1]).order_by('-working_hour')

    return render(request, "timesheet/index.html", {'events_list': events_list, 'total_hours_week': total_hours_week})
```

However, if you are using sqlite3 only for development, and you need to work with time aggregations a lot, I strongly recommend you to setup a PostgreSQL/MySql server for your development environment, as it saves you a lot of time and headache in long run.